# How can i check the Array [1,2,2,3] in the If condition

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
$array = json_decode($payment_scheme, true);
//assume the array now [1,2,2,3]
```

This is my code is not working any suggestion in if condition to check the array have values [1,2,2,3]

```
foreach($array as $payment){
    if(in_array("1223",$payment)) {
        print_r('Condition 1 CASH');
        $collection = collect();
        $collection->push();
        return response()->json(['results' => $collection], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$payment` would not be an array, it would be a string.... `1111` is not present anywhere though. You wouldn't need the `foreach` with `in_array` that searches the full array already

Comment: i decode the string to array is this wrong?
$array = json_decode($payment_scheme, true);

Comment: `$payment` is `1` then next iteration `2`, third `2`, etc. They are strings, not arrays. `$array = json_decode($payment_scheme, true);` is not wrong, your `foreach` and `is_array` logic is. Use on or the other. Iterate through and check each value with a conditional or check that the array has your value and proceed.

Comment: hello
this is the situation the controller passed a value in this type of ["1","2","2","3"] and i recieved it like this to the api part $array = json_decode($payment_scheme, true); then i used foreach to transfer it to 1223 then the 1223 is contains a 1 Means CASH 2 means Monthly 3 means Quarterly 4 means quarterly that is payment scheme then i used if condition to checked if have 1223 {return a due date }

Comment: If the array has the values `1,2,2,3`, why don't you check for that?

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is a bit flawed. You either want to use a `foreach` or an `in_array`. When iterating over a single array the values are strings, not arrays. So something like:

```
$array = [1,2,2,3];
if(in_array("1", $array)){
    echo 'the array has a 1';
}
```

could be used or:

```
foreach($array as $payment){
    if($payment == 1) {
        print_r('Condition 1 CASH');
        $collection = collect();
        $collection->push();
        return response()->json(['results' => $collection], 200);
    }
}
```

the current issue can be observed with the following debugging code:

```
$array = [1,2,2,3];
foreach($array as $payment){
    var_dump($payment);
    if(in_array("1223", $payment)) {
        //print_r('Condition 1 CASH');
        //$collection = collect();
        //$collection->push();
        //return response()->json(['results' => $collection], 200);
        echo 'is array';
    } else {
        echo 'is not array';
    }
}
```

`in_array` behavior actually changed in the latest PHP version and it throws a fatal array if an array is the second parameter.

Comment: i'm so confused :( i'm on the job training  (ojt)
my coding skill is not good

Comment: this is the situation the controller passed a value  in this type of ["1","2","2","3"]

and i recieved it like this  to the api part

 $array = json_decode($payment_scheme, true);

then i used foreach to transfer it to 
1223

then the 1223 is contains a 1 Means CASH 2 means Monthly 3 means Quarterly 4 means quarterly 

that is payment scheme  

then i used if condition to checked  if  have 1223 {return a due date }

Comment: Where's the code for `i used foreach to transfer it to 1223`? You likely should delete that

Comment: hello update po
my manager take over in my problem thank you for the time :)